# Sort two ArrayLists of integers

Tags: java, sorting

I need to sort two `ArrayList`s. For example, given

- list x = 4 6 9 9
- list y = 4 5 8 11

the result needs to be 4 5 6 8 9 9 11.

I already have this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    a.add(1);
    a.add(4);
    a.add(9);
    a.add(16);

    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    b.add(4);
    b.add(7);
    b.add(9);
    b.add(9);
    b.add(11);

    ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    c.addAll(a);
    c.addAll(b);

    int smallest = c.get(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {

        if (c.get(i) < smallest) {

            smallest = c.get(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any restrictions about what algorithm you should use?

Comment: Does `Collections.sort(c)` count as a correct answer? Or is this homework?

Comment: None of your numbers match up. The list x/y numbers include two 4s, but your result only has one 4. The `a.add` part of your code adds a 1 to the first list instead of a 6.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, the code you used below:

```
int smallest = c.get(0);

for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {

    if (c.get(i) < smallest) {

        smallest = c.get(i);
    }
}
```

**It populates the smallest element rather than sorts the list.**

You can change the for-loop,

from

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {

    if (c.get(i) < smallest) {

        smallest = c.get(i);
    }
}
```

to

```
        System.out.println("Before sorting-->" +c );
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size()-1; i++) {
       for(int j=i+1; j <c.size();j++)
       {
           if(c.get(i) > c.get(j))
           {
               int temp = c.get(j);
               c.set(j, c.get(i));
               c.set(i, temp);
           }
       }
    }
    System.out.println("After sorting-->" +c );
```

Output in Console:

```
Before sorting-->[1, 4, 9, 16, 4, 7, 9, 9, 11]
After sorting-->[1, 4, 4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 11, 16]
```

OR

You can use **`Collections.sort(List<Integer>)`** to sort the list.

Like,

```
    List<Integer> xList = Arrays.asList(4,6,9,9);
    List<Integer> yList = Arrays.asList(4,5,8,11);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    result.addAll(xList);
    result.addAll(yList);

    System.out.println("Before sorting-->" +result );

    Collections.sort(result);
    System.out.println("After sorting-->" +result );
```

Output in Console==>

```
Before sorting-->[4, 6, 9, 9, 4, 5, 8, 11]
After sorting-->[4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(arrayList);
```

for your case     `Collections.sort( c );`

Do i missing something here?